# Program to stop reading text when it finds a certain word

Tags: c

I need to write a program which reads a certain text file and shows every tenth symbol converted into ASCII code. But it needs to stop reading when it finds letters "ZZ". Also, the program shouldn't open a text file if there are less then 10 symbols or if there are no "ZZ" letters. This is the script that I have at the moment, I don't know how to write the part where the program stops to read until it finds "ZZ" and where it shouldn't open a text file if there are no letters "ZZ".

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    FILE* f1;
    FILE* f2;
    char  fn1[FILENAME_MAX];
    char  fn2[FILENAME_MAX];
    int i, c, c1;

    printf("Please write the name of your file\n");
    gets(fn1);
    f1 = fopen(fn1,"rt");
    for(i = 1;i <= 9;i++) {
        c = fgetc(f1);
            if (c == EOF ){
            perror("Error while opening file\n");
            exit`enter code here`;
        }
    }
    while( ( c = fgetc(f1) ) != EOF ){
    c1++;
        if ( c1 % 10 ==0 ){
        printf("%X ", c);
        }
    }
    fclose(f1);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: "program shouldn't open a text file ... if there are no "ZZ" letters"  Just call `CrytalBAll(filename, "ZZ");` or double check the program requirements.

Comment: If there are no "ZZ" letters in a text file that I want to open*

Comment: `f2` and `fn2` are unused; they should be removed. You should not be using `gets()` even in toy programs; it is removed from standard C11, and has been deprecated for ages (it was one of the attack vectors used in the original Internet worm in 1988 (search Google for 'morris internet worm').  Use `fgets()` instead, and remember to remove the trailing newline (or, if you're on Windows as your use of `"rt"` suggests — that is a non-portable mode for `fopen()` — then consider `gets_s()` in place of `gets()`).

Comment: checking the 'ZZ' is ok..it can be achieved but what do you mean by ' it shouldn't open a text file if there are no letters "ZZ".'???

Comment: f2 is for the second part of my script, that's why it's there, I totally forgot to remove it before posting it here, sorry for that.
And thank you for your advice, I will remember to use these commands properly from now on. 
Well I have a homework which says, that my program should open a text file and if there are no letters "ZZ" in it, that it shouldn't open it. Maybe there's something wrong with the exercise, but that's what it says. I'm just begining to learn how to write scripts in c :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there's no way to know how many ZZ or symbols without opening the file and reading it first ,but here's a piece of code that you can add to your script that would make the program stop when the line contains ZZ (it will only work if ZZ is alone in a line):

```
if(!strcmp(fgets(fn1 , sizeof fn1 , f1) , "ZZ"))
       exit(1);
```